# How to merge (left join) external node property list in python into neo4j?

Tags: python, join, neo4j

I want to "left join" a list of node property defined in python INTO neo4j for visualization. More specifically,

**Have**:

1. **neo4j**: a network which contains a total of ~16k `(:user)` nodes. The `(:user)` nodes have property `.UserId` as its unique identifier.
2. **python 3**: A list of `(UserId, Role)` illustrated below. `Role` is found by a custom algorithm in python.

   UserId Role 
   --------------- 
   5 1 
   6 3 
   7 2 
   10 0 
   .... (~16k nodes total)

**Want**:

Write `Role` back into the neo4j database for the corresponding `UserId` such that I can further colorize `(:user)` nodes by `Role`. The `Role` may be added as a tag or a property, but I am not sure which way to go.

This should be a common task in practice. But I couldn't manage to find anything relevant on google, stackoverflow and neo4j official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is in a `data` variable and you are using the [neo4j Python driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver), you can use snippet like this (passing the list in a `$list` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)):

```
query = "UNWIND $list AS ur MATCH (u:user {UserId: ur.UserId}) SET u.Role=ur.Role"
with driver.session() as session:
    with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
        tx.run(query, list=data)
```

This query would execute faster if you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:user(UserId)`.

Comment: What is the correct format for the `data` parameter? I did this as some examples given in the neo4j documentation:
`data = {
    "UserId": [dic_node_decode[i] for i in range(n)],
    "Role": [roles[i] for i in range(n)]
}`
, but I got "TypeError: Parameters of type int64 are not supported"....

Comment: It turned out that `list=` does not accept list of integers for neo4j driver 1.7.4 + python 3.6. Therefore, one must convert `data` using `str()` in python, and perform `toInteger()` when using the data. This leads to `data = [{"UserId": str(dic_node_decode[i]), "Role": str(roles[i])} for i in range(n)]` and `query = "UNWIND $list AS roleList MATCH (u:user {UserId: toInteger(roleList.UserId)}) SET u.Role = toInteger(roleList.Role)"`.